# Master Page containing silverlight control

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I’ve created a Web Site with Visual Studio 2008 3.0 framework containing a Master Page.  Is it possible to use Silverlight in a content area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Master Pages have nothing to do with Silverlight.  It will ultimately end up in generated html, with the Silverlight code inside the code generated around the content area.

Any valid html can be placed inside a content area.

And welcome to SO =)